# problem in accessing the scss variables in react components

Tags: reactjs, sass, icss

Followed the link https://mattferderer.com/use-sass-variables-in-typescript-and-javascript

Looking to access the scss varaibles in react component . Not sure with what import name i need to call in react component since if i give as below import statement it is showing an error as cannot find the module '../scss/_variables.scss';

```
import _variables from '../scss/_variables.scss';
```

here _variables.scss is the file name which contains

```
 // variables.scss
$white-color: #fcf5ed; 

:export {
  whitecolor: $white-color; }
```

I am scratching my head to get the "whitecolor" variable available in react component .

Also, I am using webpack as below

```
{
 test: '/.scss$/',
 use: [{
  loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
 }, {
  loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
 }, {
  loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
 }]
}
```

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I have a similar problem and looking for a solution...

Comment: I have used "require" to make it work .
const variables = require('../scss/_variables.scss');

Comment: I see. But did you make it work with `import`?

Comment: Below accepted answer from @yatin to use import works. I am using minicssextractplugin with webpack 5. And minicssextractplugin stopped supporting require module from 1.0.0 version. So, I had to use import rather than require module now.

Answer (score 12):

Importing specific property in React does not work unless it is a module.

I was facing the same problem and here is what I did:

Renamed `_variables.scss` to `_variables.module.scss` and then the import is `import _variables from '../scss/_variables.module.scss';`

now you can access the scss variables just like `_variables.whitecolor`

Comment: Turns out, the same solution works when you have issues importing SCSS variables in Vue.js (2.6.x).

Answer (score -1):

On the react app, you can import the variable.scss in App.scss file. If there is no file just create it.

make sure that you have installed node-sass.

```
@import "../scss/_variables.scss";
```

Now the variables are accessible, I am using React Webpack.
Also, we have other options [please check here](https://dev.to/s0xzwasd/using-scss-css-variables-in-react-322j)

Thanks,
Prem

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to `npm install node-sass`

Then change your `app.css` to `app.scss` and in there you import your stylesheet:

`@import '../scss/_variables.scss';`

Then you can use it like

```
.App-link {
  color: $secondary-color;
}
```

Comment: I want to access the scss  variables in typescript/js files not inside the other scss files . Your solution works for passing variables in scss files .