# Unable to import CSS modules into React TypeScript project #121

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

**Describe the bug**
In my React Typescript project, I am trying to use CSS modules. I created the project using **create-react-app**, added TypeScript later. Then I followed the instructions from the [docs](https://github.com/mrmckeb/typescript-plugin-css-modules#installation) to setup CSS modules in the project

1. Added the plugin with `npm install -D typescript-plugin-css-modules`
2. Then updated tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  }
}
```

3. I tried to run it but it didn't run. It complained about import statement [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-haze-ztnf6?file=/src/components/layout/header/Header.tsx:537-573). Though the plugin docs say it shouldn't
4. So I added [global.d.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-haze-ztnf6?file=/src/global.d.ts), which resolved the error
5. Now when I run it, the Home link on the header should be white. But I see the default color

**To Reproduce**

1. Go to https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-haze-ztnf6?file=/src/index.tsx
2. See the Link **Home**

**Expected behavior**
Home link color should be white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, changing the name of the scss file to **header.module.scss** fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already solved the issue, please have a look for description: [problem in accessing the scss variables in react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315250/problem-in-accessing-the-scss-variables-in-react-components/63270719#63270719)

in a similar way you can access classes from the module scss files.